# get_list_or_404 ordering in django

Tags: django

I'm trying to order the results of the get_list_or_404 method

```
get_list_or_404(...).order_by('name')
```

doesn't seem to work

What's the way to do this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can do this like this:

```
get_list_or_404(Model.objects.order_by('name'))
```

And of course you can always specify ordering in Model's `Meta` class.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your attempt didn't work is that `order_by` is a method on a queryset, but `get_list_or_404` returns a list.

The way around this problem, as Ludwik shows in his answer, is to order the queryset before calling `get_list_or_404`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have used the python's in-built reverse function to reverse the list and it worked fine.