# Ordering in get_list_or_404 in Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I am making a query in Django, which consists in an array of product Ids in a nonarbitrary order, and a list of the products which correspond to these Ids:

```
product_ids= [109, 33, 76, 332, 112]
products_inventory = get_list_or_404(Products, id__in=product_ids)
```

The query works fine. However, products_inventory doesn't have necessary the same order than the elements defined by product_ids (namely, the first element in products_inventory is not the one with id:109). How can I get the same order in products_inventory which is defined by the product_ids ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do the ordering in the database, then this answer will help you: [get_list_or_404 ordering in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658291/get-list-or-404-ordering-in-django)

If there is no relation between the ordering of the ID values you'll have to sort in python.

First create a dict converting an ID to an integer, `i`, such that when sorting on the `i` of two IDs they will be in correct order (i.e. their place in `product_ids`):

```
ordering = {id: i for i, id in enumerate(product_ids)}
```

Now create a function that takes a product and returns a value that when sorted on will put products in the correct order:

```
def keyfn(product):
    return ordering[product.id]
```

finally, sort the product inventory by `key` defined by our `keyfn`:

```
product_inventory.sort(key=keyfn)
```

Comment: Thank you @thebjorn ! In my case there were no relation, so your solution in pure python worked :)